# How Does ASP.NET MVC Load jQuery Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a minimal ASP.NET MVC 5 app that was generated via Scaffolding. When I look at the generated `_Layout.cshtml` file I see a `<script>` tag toward the bottom of the page that loads jQuery but nowhere in `_Layout.cshtm` do I see a reference to a jQuery Validation module in a `<script>` tag.

If I go into Chrome Developer Tools, under the "Sources" tab, I can see that indeed jQuery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrisuve *are loaded*! But how can they be loaded if they were not referenced by a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Most likely loaded in the view with a partial include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in `App_Start BundleConfig.cs` you should see reference to:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

which defines the jQuery validation script bundle. Certain scaffold pages (for example Login) have:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

referenced at the bottom of the View.

This is picked up by `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` at the bottom of `_Layout` (which renders the script if it is defined).

Comment: Yes, you basically got it right! At the bottom of the generated Edit.cshtml is a <script> tag that pulls in the jQuery validation libraries. Thank you.

Comment: Heh - nice one - it's quite hidden if you're not looking for it. Mystery solved.